# Clone an image from a docker registry to another

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a private registry with a set of images. It can be visualized as a store of applications.
My app can take these applications and run them on other machines.
To achieve this, my app first pull the image from the private registry and then copies it to a local registry for later use.

Step as are follow:

```
docker pull privateregistry:5000/company/app:tag
docker tag privateregistry:5000/company/app:tag localregistry:5000/company/app:tag
docker push localregistry:5000/company/app:tag
```

Then later on a different machine in my network:

```
docker pull localregistry:5000/company/app:tag
```

Is there a way to efficiently copy an image from a repository to another without using a docker client in between ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `docker save` to save the images to tar archive and then copy the tar to new host and use `docker load` to untar it.

read below links for more
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Comment: Yeah, this works, but it is a very large image.  But it will get the job done without having to use a container registry.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to efficiently copy an image from a repository to another without using a docker client in between?

Yes, there's a variety of tools that implement this today. RedHat has been pushing their skopeo, Google has [crane](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/crane/doc/crane.md), and I've been working on my own with [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient). Each of these tools talks directly to the registry server without needing a docker engine. And at least with regclient (I haven't tested the others), these will only copy the layers that are not already in the target registry, avoiding the need to pull layers again. Additionally, you can move a multi-platform image, retaining all of the available platforms, which you would lose with a `docker pull` since that dereferences the image to a single platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo):

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${HOME}/.docker/config.json:/config.json:ro quay.io/skopeo/stable:latest copy --authfile /config.json docker://${SRC_IMAGE} docker://${DST_IMAGE}
```

where `SRC_IMAGE` and `DST_IMAGE` are full paths to docker images, including registry URL, image name, and tag. Note that for Docker Hub links, you may need to include the registry URL `docker.io` e.g. `docker.io/linuxserver/wireguard:legacy`

The above command assumes your docker credentials for logging into your private registry are in the standard location `~/.docker/config.json`