# How to copy public images like java, busybox to Amazon Elastic Container Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerhub, elastic-container-registry

I have a scenario where I have to pull the images from Amazon Elastic Container Service instead of Docker Hub to avoid the pull rate limit error or to reduce the calls to dockerhub. Is it possible to copy public images from Docker hub to Amazon Elastic Container Service?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is "pull through cache repositories" in ECR. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-pull-through-cache-repositories-for-amazon-elastic-container-registry/

Comment: The public ECR repo, linked in the answer below, is almost certainly your best option. But to answer your specific question, you just run the following 3 commands: `docker pull <image>` the `docker tag <image> <your-ecr-repo-url>:<tag>` then `docker push <your-ecr-repo-url>:<tag>`.

Comment: Are you trying to [Clone an image from a docker registry to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974656/clone-an-image-from-a-docker-registry-to-another), but where the source is public Docker Hub?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it is Docker hub.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has its own [public Docker repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/what-is-ecr.html). Check these images here https://gallery.ecr.aws/.

I.e. [Java](https://gallery.ecr.aws/bitnami/java), [Busybox](https://gallery.ecr.aws/docker/library/busybox)